# de Rham cohomology group and Dolbeault cohomology group on compact complex analytic spaces

Tags: complex-geometry, hodge-theory, several-complex-variables

My question is:

On a compact complex analytic space,since Hodge Theorem becomes invalid,is it true that the de Rham cohomology group $H^p_{DR}(M)$ and the Dolbeault cohomology group $H^{p,q}_{\bar{\partial}}(M)$ are still finite dimensional?Here de Rham and Dolbeault cohomology groups refer to,in common sense,quotient of closed forms and exact forms.

Let's define differential forms on complex analytic spaces.The following definitions are cited from J.R.King's paper 'The currents defined by analytic varieties'.

Let $X$ be a reduced complex space, and $X_{reg}$, which is a complex manifold, be the set of nonsingular points in $X$.

Suppose that $X$ is  a subvariety of a complex manifold $M$. Let $I_X^{p, q}(M)= \{\alpha\in A^{p, q}(M) \mid i^*\alpha= 0\}$, where $i: X_{reg}\rightarrow M$ is the inclusion. Define $A^{p, q}(X):= A^{p, q}(M)/I_X^{p, q}(M)$. It can be shown that $A^{p, q}(X)$ is independent of the embedding. Hence, for any complex space $X$, we can define $A^{p, q}(X)$ by using the local embeddings in $\mathbb{C}^N$.

We can naturally define $\partial:A^{p, q}(X)\rightarrow A^{p+1, q}(X)$,  $\overline{\partial}:A^{p, q}(X)\rightarrow A^{p, q+1}(X)$ and $d:A^k(X)\rightarrow A^{k+1}(X)$.

If $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is a holomorphic map of reduced complex spaces, then we can naturally define $f^*:A^{p, q}(Y)\rightarrow A^{p, q}(X)$ such that $f^\ast$ commutes with $\partial$, $\overline{\partial}$, $d$.

In complex manifold case,we have

because of Hodge Theorem,the de Rham cohomology group $H^p_{DR}(M)$ and the Dolbeault cohomology group $H^{p,q}_{\bar{\partial}}(M)$ are finite dimensional.

But when the situation changes into complex analytic space,I'm not sure whether the above facts still hold.

I know that there is a paper 'de Rham cohomology on an analytic space' written by T.Bloom and M.Herrera.But they seem to define the de Rham cohomology to be hypercohomology,not the same thing as I defined.

Can you give me some suggestions?Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused, is $A^{p,q}(X)$ just $A^{p,q}(X_{reg})$?  E.g. you could take the map $i$ to be the identity.

Comment: @EricO.Korman I don't think so.In a neighborhood of a singular point,we should have some information on singular locus by continuity.If you take the map $i$ to be the identity,you will simply let the value of the coefficients of the differential forms on the singular locus to be zero,which lead to lose informations on singular locus.

Comment: Oops, missed the part where $X$ is a subvariety of $M$.

Comment: You can consult V. Ancona, B. Gaveau (2005) _Differential Forms on Singular Varieties: De Rham and Hodge Theory Simplified_, Chapmann & Hall. The authors develop a (possible version of) De Rham cohomology theory for complex analytic spaces, as you describe, via **desingularization** of these spaces.

Comment: Everytime I see this question, I am confused as to how the manifold case works. If $M$ is Kahler, we use the Hodge theorem. If $M$ is algebraic, we can use Chow's Lemma. But why do we know $H^q(\Omega^p)$ is finite dimensional for a compact, non-Kahler, non-algebraic complex manifold?

Comment: This follows from some sort-of Hodge-decomposition for elliptic complexes, as can be found in Wells' book, @DavidESpeyer. It just involves harder analysis than in the Kähler case.